# How to assign a group based on consecutive sum in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe as below:

```
A         B          code cumul_sum
group1    group1_1    A     1
group1    group1_1    A     2
group1    group1_1    B     1
group1    group1_1    A     1
group1    group1_1    A     2
group1    group1_1    A     3 
group2    group2_1    A     1
group2    group2_1    A     2
group2    group2_1    A     3
```

Please assume column A and B are belonging to same category. I wanted to group and the expected result are as follows

```
A         B          code cumul_sum   **groupcat**
group1    group1_1    A     1          group1
group1    group1_1    A     2          group1
group1    group1_1    B     1          group2
group1    group1_1    A     1          group3
group1    group1_1    A     2          group3
group1    group1_1    A     3          group3
group2    group2_1    A     1          group1
group2    group2_1    A     2          group1
group2    group2_1    A     3          group1
```

Since there is a code B that occurred in the middle, group1 is not assigned to the third row and then the next value is a fresh categorical value.

EDIT:
To also reset the group-cat for group A and B.

Please advice

Answer (score 2):

You can modify [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73970316/2901002):

```
#tested consecutive values by code column
s = df['code'].ne(df['code'].shift()).cumsum()
df['groupcat'] = 'group' + s.astype(str)

print (df)
        A         B code  cumul_sum groupcat
0  group1  group1_1    A          1   group1
1  group1  group1_1    A          2   group1
2  group1  group1_1    B          1   group2
3  group1  group1_1    A          1   group3
4  group1  group1_1    A          2   group3
5  group1  group1_1    A          3   group3
```

---

```
#tested consecutive groups by A, B, code
s = df[['A','B','code']].ne(df[['A','B','code']].shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()
df['groupcat'] = 'group' + s.astype(str)

print (df)
        A         B code  cumul_sum groupcat
0  group1  group1_1    A          1   group1
1  group1  group1_1    A          2   group1
2  group1  group1_1    B          1   group2
3  group1  group1_1    A          1   group3
4  group1  group1_1    A          2   group3
5  group1  group1_1    A          3   group3
```

EDIT:

```
s = df['code'].ne(df['code'].shift()).cumsum()


df['group'] = ('group' + df.assign(s=s)
                           .groupby(['A','B'])['s']
                           .rank('dense').astype(int).astype(str))
print (df)
        A         B code  cumul_sum   group
0  group1  group1_1    A          1  group1
1  group1  group1_1    A          2  group1
2  group1  group1_1    B          1  group2
3  group1  group1_1    A          1  group3
4  group1  group1_1    A          2  group3
5  group1  group1_1    A          3  group3
6  group2  group2_1    A          1  group1
7  group2  group2_1    A          2  group1
8  group2  group2_1    A          3  group1
```

Alternative solution:

```
s = (df[['A','B','code']].ne(df[['A','B','code']].shift()).any(axis=1)
        .groupby([df.A, df.B]).cumsum())
df['groupcat'] = 'group' + s.astype(str)

print (df)
        A         B code  cumul_sum groupcat
0  group1  group1_1    A          1   group1
1  group1  group1_1    A          2   group1
2  group1  group1_1    B          1   group2
3  group1  group1_1    A          1   group3
4  group1  group1_1    A          2   group3
5  group1  group1_1    A          3   group3
6  group2  group2_1    A          1   group1
7  group2  group2_1    A          2   group1
8  group2  group2_1    A          3   group1
```

Comment: Is it possible to reset the group<<n>> ..where n resets to every group category A and B and start from 1 again

Comment: @python_interest - Not sure if understand, can you change sample data?

Comment: added the new sample data

Answer (score 1):

Since your groups ignore the code, you can just restart on each 1 value:

```
df['groupcat'] = df['cumul_sum'].eq(1).cumsum()
```

As string:

```
df['groupcat'] = df['cumul_sum'].eq(1).cumsum().astype(str).radd('group')
```

output:

```
        A         B code  cumul_sum groupcat
0  group1  group1_1    A          1   group1
1  group1  group1_1    A          2   group1
2  group1  group1_1    B          1   group2
3  group1  group1_1    A          1   group3
4  group1  group1_1    A          2   group3
5  group1  group1_1    A          3   group3
```